# NPM is not recognized as an internal/external command

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

My package.json file for the server folder I'm trying to start:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon src/app.js --exec 'npm run lint && node'",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint **/*.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.12.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.12.1"
  }
}
```

I do not know why it doesn't notice npm from the package.json start script when npm runs perfectly when it's not being executed through package.json.

Anyone know why? I'm trying to learn Full Stack development and I am confused on this error.

Edit: I'm running Windows 10.

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: Windows 10 is my OS

Comment: what does `npm -v ` gives??

Comment: Are you using node on `windows subsystem for Linux` by any chance?

Comment: Version 5.5.1 of NPM and I'm not using node on a Linux or subsystem. I have a microsoft pro.

Answer (score 1):

Use **double quotes** in your script as **single quotes** won't recognize in Windows command line.

Change your `start` to:

```
"start": "nodemon src/app.js --exec \"npm run lint && node\"",
```